# How to create email hyperlink with predefined subject in LaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, links

I´m wondering if you can include an email hyperlink in a PDF, that will not only open my mail application with the specified mail address, but also insert a subject, which I specified in LaTeX?

I found something, that hints in the right direction, however, I seem to be unable to make it work. There is the "pracjourn" class, which is supposed to have this implemented in the following macro from http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/pracjourn/pracjourn.pdf (p.15):

> This macro takes three arguments to typeset a mailto email hyperlink. The #1
>   takes the email address, #2 takes the default subject of the email, and #3 is the
>   text to appear in the output as the hyperlink.

```
230 \newcommand\tpj@compose@mailto[3]{%
231 \edef\@tempa{mailto:#1?subject=#2 }%
232 \edef\@tempb{\expandafter\html@spaces\@tempa\@empty}%
233 \href{\@tempb}{#3}}
```

I don´t really know what to do with that macro... Even using the pracjourn class doesn´t support this command, which is obviously due to the @ in the command name and I can only guess, that this is not meant for LaTeX, but TeX?!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As to the `@`, see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351)

Comment: It'd be curious to know, if you could add a text body as well...

Answer (score 12):

Your copied piece of code is not complete. If you look into the pdf you will find a few more lines.

I put all together to a compiling MWE:

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myemail[3]{%                %\newcommand\tpj@compose@mailto[3]{%
\edef\@tempa{mailto:#1?subject=#2 }%
\edef\@tempb{\expandafter\html@spaces\@tempa\@empty}%
\href{\@tempb}{#3}}

\catcode\%=11
\def\html@spaces#1 #2{#1%20\ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\html@spaces\fi#2}
\catcode\%=14
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\section{Test Email}

An email adress: \myemail{john.doe@doe.ab}{Subjekt}{Text in pdf}

\end{document}
```

I renamed the macro to `\myemail` and it needs 3 arguments, the email adress to send to (`john.doe@doe.ab`), the subject (`Subjekt`) and an text (`Text in pdf`) to be showed in the resulting pdf for the link (could be the email adress, if you want).
The macro `\html@space` changes the blanks to `%20`.

Comment: is it correct that the part of code after `\def\html@spaces#1 #2{#1` seems to be commented because of `%`?